# pandas calculating a shifted rolling variance by group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas-dataframe holding a GROUP, DATE, VALUE and VARIANCE column:

```
Index      GROUP   DATE         VALUE    VARIANCE
1          g1      2015-12-02   10       3.2                    
2          g1      2015-10-12   9        4.25                  
3          g1      2013-12-13   8        8               
4          g1      2013-12-13   11       8
5          g1      2013-07-15   7        NaN
6          g1      2015-12-02   11       NaN                   
7          g2            ...
```

Basically I want to calculate the shifted rolling variance for the VALUE column. So the value for variance for Index 1 is the variance over the values in Index 2-6, etc.

My first approach was to use an expanding windown to calculate the variances and shift the values by 1 but I am not sure whether this is the right approach here. I am happy about every suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `pd.expanding` on the `VALUE` column you should first flip the dataframe and calculate the expanding variance shifted:

```
variance = df['VALUE'].iloc[::-1].expanding(
          ).var().shift().iloc[::-1].rename('VARIANCE')

>> variance

Index
1    3.200000
2    4.250000
3    5.333333
4    8.000000
5         NaN
6         NaN
Name: VARIANCE, dtype: float64
```

**Multiple Groups**

Let us create a new df with values for each group:

```
>> df

      GROUP        DATE  VALUE
Index                         
1        g1  2015-12-02     10
2        g1  2015-10-12      9
3        g1  2013-12-13      8
4        g1  2013-12-13     11
5        g1  2013-07-15      7
6        g1  2015-12-02     11
1        g2  2015-12-02     10
2        g2  2015-10-12      9
3        g2  2013-12-13      8
4        g2  2013-12-13     11
5        g2  2013-07-15      7
6        g2  2015-12-02     11
```

For multiple groups you can [iterate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) over the groups and store the results.

```
variance = []

for name, group in df.groupby('GROUP'):
      variance.append(group['VALUE'].iloc[::-1].expanding(
                      ).var().shift().iloc[::-1])

>> df.assign(VARIANCE=pd.concat(variance))

      GROUP        DATE  VALUE  VARIANCE
Index                                   
1        g1  2015-12-02     10  3.200000
2        g1  2015-10-12      9  4.250000
3        g1  2013-12-13      8  5.333333
4        g1  2013-12-13     11  8.000000
5        g1  2013-07-15      7       NaN
6        g1  2015-12-02     11       NaN
1        g2  2015-12-02     10  3.200000
2        g2  2015-10-12      9  4.250000
3        g2  2013-12-13      8  5.333333
4        g2  2013-12-13     11  8.000000
5        g2  2013-07-15      7       NaN
6        g2  2015-12-02     11       NaN
```

Comment: It wasn't clear in the question. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone looking into this question. Mabel Villalba's answer pointed me in the right direction. I altered her approach accordingly:

```
variance_r = df[['GROUP','DATE','VALUE']].sort_values(['GROUP','DATE'])
variance = []

for name, group in variance_r.groupby('GROUP'):
    variance.append(
                    group['VALUE'].expanding().var().shift(1).
                    where(group['DATE'].shift() != group['DATE'],
                    group['VALUE'].expanding().var().shift(2)
                    ))

variance_r.assign(VARIANCE = pd.concat(variance))
```